# The 'pip==20.3.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Tags: python, bash, macos, module, pip

I'm trying to install a module with pip but I'm getting this error screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3095, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3081, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3108, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 846, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.3.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade pip version?

Comment: @assli100 I want to but I can't do anything with pip and python.

Comment: @assli100 when I write the command "python -m pip install -upgrade pip" it says /usr/bin/python: No module named pip

Comment: And when you try "/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install -upgrade pip"?

Comment: It didn't work. @assli100

Comment: where is the pip binary located?

Comment: @assli100 how can I learn?